# CSS: Need help how to get my two items in my container to be placed correctly

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a problem with how i am supposed to center my text in the middle of the box and get my number (01, 02 etc) in the top left corner?

I am using flexbox to first center all my contents and then align-self my heading to flex start. All fine and dandy but as you can see my heading is not in the top right corner. How would i make sure the heading is in the top left corner and my text is in the center of the box and not slightly off center?

I have tried to set margin right on auto to push the heading to the left, it works but my text is then pushed all the way to the right.

How would I go ahead of fixing this?

```css
footer {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
}

.box {
  min-height: 354.48px;
  max-height: 354.48px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.box h2 {
  font-size: 2rem;
}

.how-it-works {
  background-color: #c7ddea;
}

.O1 {
  background-color: white;
}

.O1 h2 {
  align-self: flex-start;
}

.O2 {
  background-color: #e7e7e7;
}

.O2 h2 {
  align-self: flex-start;
}

.O3 {
  background-color: #fff;
}

.O3 h2 {
  align-self: flex-start;
}

.O4 {
  background-color: #f17949;
}

.O4 h2 {
  align-self: flex-start;
}

.O5 {
  background-color: #fff;
}

.O5 h2 {
  align-self: flex-start;
}
```

```html
<footer>
  <div class="box how-it-works">
    <h1>How it works?</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="box O1">
    <h2>01</h2>
    <p>Answer a few questions about yourself</p>
  </div>
  <div class="box O2">
    <h2>02</h2>
    <p>Choose a plan. Get a quote.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="box O3">
    <h2>03</h2>
    <p>Answe some questions about your medical history</p>
  </div>
  <div class="box O4">
    <h2>04</h2>
    <p>Wait 90 sec to get approved.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="box O5">
    <h2>05</h2>
    <p>Done!</p>
  </div>
</footer>
```

[image]

Comment: html & css code?

Comment: One sec, it apperently didnt show here.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```css
footer {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
}

.box {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 354.48px;
  max-height: 354.48px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.box h2 {
  font-size: 2rem;
  line-height: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 1rem;
  left: 1rem;
}

.box p {
  text-align: center;
}

.how-it-works {
  background-color: #c7ddea;
}

.O1 {
  background-color: white;
}

.O2 {
  background-color: #e7e7e7;
}

.O3 {
  background-color: #fff;
}

.O4 {
  background-color: #f17949;
}

.O5 {
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

```html
  <footer>
  <div class="box how-it-works"><h1>How it works?</h1></div>
  <div class="box O1">
    <h2>01</h2>
    <p>Answer a few questions about yourself</p>
  </div>
  <div class="box O2">
    <h2>02</h2>
    <p>Choose a plan. Get a quote.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="box O3">
    <h2>03</h2>
    <p>Answe some questions about your medical history</p>
  </div>
  <div class="box O4">
    <h2>04</h2>
    <p>Wait 90 sec to get approved.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="box O5">
    <h2>05</h2>
    <p>Done!</p>
  </div>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood well what you need, one solution could be adding this to `.box` class:

```
.box{
    flex-direction: column;
}
```